# Whats the number of steps this algorithm will take for the general case where the input is of size n?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Here's the algorithm:

```
Let a = 30, i = 1
While i < n
    For j = i+1 to n
        If ABS[(j*i)+20] < a then a = ABS[(j*i)+20]
    i = i + 1
Return k
```

Whats the number of steps this algorithm will take for the general case where the input is of size n? How do you work that out?

Also does this algorithm come under the quadratic complexity class?

Comment: Why the square brackets after ABS?  Are those round parentheses, maybe representing the absolute value function?

Comment: @JirkaHanika Or it's an array, not that I think it matters for the question.

Comment: Count it. How many instructions are there when n = 3, 4, 5... Can you generalize it?

Comment: urrr... I just want to post the `O(n)` answer, the indent in question codes is changed.....

Comment: There's something weird happening with `n`.  Either you have input of size `n`, or you have an input that you call `n` (that is, whose *value* is called `n`), but not both.  The size of `n` is, in normal circumstances, the logarithm of `n`.

Comment: @Kent It started with no indentation, then someone indented it, but that indentation (while perfectly valid) didn't seem like a very probable way to do things, so I fixed it (it's entirely possible that I'm wrong). The indentation when giving pseudo-code should've been correct to start since there's no standard on how it's processed.

Comment: @Dukeling - you are right, it does not necessarily matter, but I am starting to lean toward the theory that this is just a character soup and not software.  That's usually the case for code where the difference between the `ABS` function and an array of obscure name does not really matter for an answer.

Comment: @Dukeling I think your edit is good. otherwise the `while` doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Too localized. It is unlikely that anybody will have to study this specific algorithm in the future, and even if they did, the generic sounding title will not help them find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is with `O(n^2)`

we have

```
n+(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)......[total n] ....3.2.1
```

if we calculate it, it would be

```
0.5( (n^2) + n) = C (n^2 + n)
```

and it is  quadratic complexity class.

Comment: How would I work out the number of steps when n=5?

Comment: @user2269663 I just notice the i is from 1, not 0, then in total we have `n-1`, so it looks like `1+2+3+...+(n-1)` so still `O(n^2)`  if you have n=5, then `4+3+2+1`

Comment: so would it be something like this to work out n=5... (i)+(i+1)+(i+2)...+(n-1)?

Comment: you are welcome. you could take a pencil and a piece of paper, take `n=1,2,3,4,5... ` then you see the rule.  two nested loop till n would have `O(n^2)` for big-O, you could google/wikipedia big-O notation for detail. PS. you could upvote answers gave you help, and   mark the answer, which solved your problem as "accepted". you can see the tick around the up/down arrow (for up/downvote) and zero beside each answer.

Comment: Thanks. You don't mind explaining how you got the answer to n=5 again please? How would I show the working? The answer you gave is right, I don't know how to put that on paper with working out

Comment: @user2269663 yes like what you posted in the other comment.

Comment: so to work out n=5, you do i+(i+1)+(i+2)...+(n-1)? How would I prove that this was the method, because you worked it out for me. Was there a way you came to this conclusion?

Comment: first, i=1. the formular is like 1+...+(n-1), then we calculate this, `((1+(n-1))*(n-1) )/2`  result `C (n^2 + n)` ---> quadratic is that clear?

Comment: thanks I kind of get it now. What does 1+...+(n-1) mean again?

Comment: could you please elaborate on the ((1+(n-1))*(n-1))/2 bit please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Answer (score 0):

Let f(i) denote the number of times the inner for loop runs assuming that j goes from i+1 to n. For example f(5) = n - 5 + 1, since j goes through 6,7,...,n. So we want f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(n - 1). Compute what each f(i) and then sum them to see the exact answer.

In general there is an outer loop that runs n times, then the inner loop runs at most n times, for a complexity upper bounded by ???

Answer (score 0):

If I was a compiler, I would notice that this code only changes `i`, `j`, and `a`, local variables; and the only variable whose value is subsequently used is `k`.  So I would gradually optimize away everything but this:

```
Return k
```

and the computation would be all constant time, just a few machine instructions.  Therefore also within quadratic time.